# Transposing 'Accounts' hierarchy to flat table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, gnucash

Wanting to create some reporting on my GnuCash DB in MariaDB, I'm trying to transpose the `accounts` table into a flat table. In essence, the `Accounts` table contains each Account with an ID (`guid`) as well as a PARENT_ID (`parent_guid`). The top account has an `account_type` = 'ROOT' and is named 'Root Account'.

Knowing I have a maximum of 4 levels down from the top account (i.e. 5 levels including 'Root Account') I'm looking to translate this to a table having the following columns:

- Account ID (`guid`)
- Account name (`name`)
- Level 1 (The Account Name 1 level down from the 'Root Account')
- Level 2 (The Account Name 2 levels down from the 'Root Account')
- Level 3 (The Account Name 3 levels down from the 'Root Account')
- Level 4 (The Account Name 4 levels down from the 'Root Account')

The accounts table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
    `guid` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `name` VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `account_type` VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `commodity_guid` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `commodity_scu` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `non_std_scu` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `parent_guid` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `code` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `description` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `hidden` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `placeholder` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`guid`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

My solution:

```
SELECT a1.guid AS a_guid,
            a1.name AS L1,
            NULL AS L2,
            NULL AS L3,
            NULL AS L4,
            IF(a1.name LIKE '%Inkomen', -1, 1) AS multiplier
FROM gnucash.accounts a1
JOIN gnucash.accounts a0 ON a0.guid = a1.parent_guid AND a0.name = 'Root Account'

UNION ALL

SELECT a2.guid AS a_guid,
            a1.name AS L1,
            a2.name AS L2,
            NULL AS L3,
            NULL AS L4,
            IF(a1.name LIKE '%Inkomen', -1, 1) AS multiplier
FROM gnucash.accounts a2
JOIN gnucash.accounts a1 ON a1.guid = a2.parent_guid
JOIN gnucash.accounts a0 ON a0.guid = a1.parent_guid AND a0.name = 'Root Account'

UNION ALL

SELECT a3.guid AS a_guid,
            a1.name AS L1,
            a2.name AS L2,
            a3.name AS L3,
            NULL AS L4,
            IF(a1.name LIKE '%Inkomen', -1, 1) AS multiplier
FROM gnucash.accounts a3
JOIN gnucash.accounts a2 ON a2.guid = a3.parent_guid
JOIN gnucash.accounts a1 ON a1.guid = a2.parent_guid
JOIN gnucash.accounts a0 ON a0.guid = a1.parent_guid AND a0.name = 'Root Account'

UNION ALL

SELECT a4.guid AS a_guid,
            a1.name AS L1,
            a2.name AS L2,
            a3.name AS L3,
            a4.name AS L4,
            IF(a1.name LIKE '%Inkomen', -1, 1) AS multiplier
FROM gnucash.accounts a4
JOIN gnucash.accounts a3 ON a3.guid = a4.parent_guid
JOIN gnucash.accounts a2 ON a2.guid = a3.parent_guid
JOIN gnucash.accounts a1 ON a1.guid = a2.parent_guid
JOIN gnucash.accounts a0 ON a0.guid = a1.parent_guid AND a0.name = 'Root Account'
```

Which makes me wonder: isn't there a more efficient and elegant way to create this view?
I've tried different `JOIN`s, but haven't been able to avoid the `UNION` of each level.

I've tried [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query), but this just gives me a list of all accounts related to one top-level parent. I'm trying to convert it to a table:
| `guid` | `name` | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 | Level 4 |
And I'm trying to have all accounts be included, including mid-level accounts (like my solution does)

- @MatBailie #1: sorry, I should've just copied the cte. Adjusted.
- @MatBailie #2: I don't control the underlying database design for GnuCash, hence I can't change the use of `guid`.
- @MatBailie #3: thank you.
- @Bill Karwin: `10.11.4-MariaDB-1:10.11.4+maria~ubu2204`

Comment: Please make this a [mre] by removing the columns not relevant and adding example data to demonstrate data you do / do not experience, plus the results you need for the example data you give. (For example, your query references splits and transactions, but you do not describe them at all. If they're not relevant to your question, please remove them from the query you want help with.)

Comment: Separately, I suggest researching the relative merits of using a GUID as a primary key. Generally speaking, it's a bad idea as it causes page fragmentation, is oversized for its normal use, etc. By all means have a GUID as a secondary surrogate or natural key, but using a integer identity column as a primary key for relational integrity is very usually preferred.

Comment: Thirdly, you will get immediate performance improvement if you use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. Doing so will avoid unnecessary resource costs associates with `UNION` running a deduplication.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on your instance?